# Using SendMessage to get a CString value?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, sendmessage

Using `SendMessage` I can pass a `CString` up to the parent easily enough (simplified):

```
CString strText = L"The text";
GetParent()->SendMessage(theApp.UWM_LOADED_SRR_FILE_MSG, 
                        reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(strText.GetString()));
```

Parent handler:

```
afx_msg LRESULT CMyDialog::OnSetSRRFilename(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPCTSTR szFilename = reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(wParam);

    // Do something.

    return 0;
}
```

That works, but what about the other way? How can I use messaging to get the current CString value from the parent? I know I can just cast to the parent object type and call the public method. But I want to use messaging. The way I understand it is that SendMessage is passing to a location to receive text.

Am I supposed to post a message to parent that says "i want the string" passing the handle of my window. And then in that handler it sends a message to that handle with the string value?

Am I overcomplicating this?

The string value is not a control, just a private variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply define a message asking for the text. The caller (child) must have a buffer to receive the text. `wParam` can be the buffer length and `lParam` the buffer (pointer).

Alternatively, the message return value can be a memory object (handle or pointer) eg allocated by the parent and freed by the child. For an example of how the message could be defined check the [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-gettext) message; for the alternative case the [`GetClipboardData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata) function.

Third alternative, the message return-value can be a `CString*`, containing the requested text. It must be allocated by the parent by calling `new`, copy-constructed from the original. On return the child "owns" the object and must free it by calling `delete`. Or the message could just return the address of the `CString` object, or even its buffer (call `GetString()`) - in these cases it is considered "read-only" for the child.

Comment: Thanks. Both parent / client have a CString. So it would be nice to use GetString for consistency. Whichever is easiest.

Comment: So I cast GetString to a LRESULT?

Comment: I think your third option it simplest. Return GetString. So I would cast to lresult and my send message code would cast the return value back to the buffer.

Comment: Yes, you have to cast the message return-value to `LPCTSTR` (`C` for const, ie it is read-only for the child) - if you don't need to modify or "own" the string object this is the simplest solution (assuming the parent won't be modifying it for as long as it is being used by the child). It is also the leanest/fastest as no copies are made or objects allocated/released.

Comment: Re: `(assuming the parent won't be modifying it for as long as it is being used by the child)` - this should be in **BOLD** in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If this were inter-process communication, then you would consider `SendMessage`, `WM_COPYDATA`, clipboard, etc.

But it looks like you are working on a single-threaded application. You don't need the added complexity of windows message handling. Just use standard c++ to call the functions in other classes directly. For example,

```
auto ptr = dynamic_cast<CMyParent*>(GetParent());
if (ptr)
{
    CString str;
    ptr->GetSRRFilename(str);
    ptr->SetSRRFilename(str);
    ...
}
else
{
    MessageBox("cast failed, \
            parent is not CMyParent class. We are not interested.");
}
```

Or use `static_cast` if you are sure that `GetParent()` is a `CMyParent` class.

I don't know about the design of your classes. Maybe you have `CMyParent1` and `CMyParent2`, they share some functions and it's difficult to tie them together (but it shouldn't be impossible), in that case you can use `SendMessage` as a cheat.

Comment: Hi. I did state I did not want to cast. I do have two parent editors and I did not want to introduce any header inclusion headaches between the two so I used the message approach to avoid any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments I now have this solution:

```
afx_msg LRESULT CMyDialog::OnGetSRRFilename(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(GetLastEditedSRRFile().GetString());
}
```

And in my dialog that needs to get the data:

```
const auto szFileName = reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(GetParent()->SendMessage(theApp.UWM_GET_SRR_FILENAME_MSG));
```

Works fine!